# Asp.net webapi 2 for load balanced scenarios

Tags: token, asp.net-web-api2, owin, asp.net-mvc-5.2

I am using Asp.net webapi2 , ASP.Net Identity and OWIN for authenticating and authorizing my webAPI controller methods.

Can you give me the approach/solution (keeping in mind the best practices) for:

1. How to Handle access_token for load balanced based scenarios, e.g for the request when access_token is generated from server A and then while getting data from one of the webmethod request goes to server B. In this case, access_token will not be valid on server B and will throw Unauthorized error. What is the best way to handle this?
2. best way to implement Refresh token Implementation?

Thanks..